# Error in installing matlab on Fedora Linux

Tags: linux, matlab, installation, fedora

I'm trying to install `matlab R2008b student` on Fedora Linux. When I run `/.install`, I get the following (how can I fix this issue)?

```
 An error status was returned by the program 'xsetup',
    the X Window System version of 'install'. The following
    messages were written to standard error:

        /home/abder-rahman/Desktop/tmp/update/install/main.sh: line 86: /home/abder-rahman/Desktop/tmp/update/bin/glnxa64/xsetup: No such file or directory

    Attempt to fix the problem and try again. If X is not available
    or 'xsetup' cannot be made to work then try the terminal
    version of 'install' using the command:

            install* -t    or    INSTALL* -t
```

Thanks.

Comment: This is [off-topic for Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions). You might want to ask about this on [Unix.SE](http://unix.stackexchange.com) or [Super User](http://superuser.com) (but search for it there first!).

Answer (score 1):

You have to install some xserver related packages. Assuming you have ubuntu `sudo apt-get install xserver-core xserver-common`

If you have connected to the system (that want to install Matlab) remotely through `ssh`, remember to use `-X` option.